# TypeError: stores.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, google-api-nodejs-client

I am creating store locator app using Nodejs and MongoDB.
Can't be able to retrieve data from MongoDB to my API. Connection between Postman and MongoDB is working perfectly, I can see data in MongoDB but not be able to get data from MongoDB to my frontend API.    forEach loop is not working

app.js

```
const {response} = require('express')
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
const Store = require('./api/models/store')

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
  next();
}) 

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://ashish_pwj:<password>@cluster0.vujgx.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority', {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});

app.use(express.json({
  limit: '50mb'
}))

app.get('/api/stores', (req, res) => {
  let dbStores = [];
  let stores = req.body;
  stores.forEach((store) => {
    dbStores.push({
      storeName: store.name,
      phoneNumber: store.phoneNumber,
      address: store.address,
      openStatusText: store.openStatusText,
      addressLines: store.addressLines,
      location: {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [
          store.coordinates.longitude,
          store.coordinates.latitude
        ]
      }
    })
  });

  Store.create(dbStores, (err, stores)=>{
    if(err){
      res.status(500).send(err)
    } else {
      res.status(200).send(stores)
    }
  })

  // console.log(dbStores)
  // console.log('HERE!')
  // console.log(req)
  /*var store = new Store({
    storeName: "test",
    phoneNumber: "2629265158",
    location: {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
        -122.5,
        37.7
      ]
    }
  })
  store.save()*/  
  // res.send('You have posted')
})

app.delete('/api/stores', (req, res) => {
  Store.deleteMany({}, (err)=>{
    res.status(200).send(err)
  })
})

app.get('/api/stores', (req, res) => {
  // res.send('Hello World!')
  Store.find({}, (err, stores)=>{
    if(err) {
      res.status(500).send(err)
    } else {
      res.status(200).send(stores)
    }
  })
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Request Json of One Store:

```
{
    "recommendation": {},
    "storeNumber": "5758-13907",
    "id": "15051",
    "name": "La Cienega & Gregory Way",
    "phoneNumber": "310-659-9562",
    "coordinates": {
        "latitude": 34.063584,
        "longitude": -118.376354
    },
    "regulations": [],
    "address": {
        "streetAddressLine1": "257 S. La Cienega Blvd.",
        "streetAddressLine2": null,
        "streetAddressLine3": null,
        "city": "Beverly Hills",
        "countrySubdivisionCode": "CA",
        "countryCode": "US",
        "postalCode": "902113301"
    },
    "timeZoneInfo": {
        "currentTimeOffset": -420,
        "windowsTimeZoneId": "Pacific Standard Time",
        "olsonTimeZoneId": "GMT-08:00 America/Los_Angeles"
    },
    "brandName": "Starbucks",
    "ownershipTypeCode": "CO",
    "open": true,
    "openStatusText": "Open until 6:00 PM",
    "addressLines": ["257 S. La Cienega Blvd.", "Beverly Hills, CA 90211"],
    "mop": {
        "ready": false,
        "wait": null
    }
}
```

Respons Json snippet for one store which i got from Postman:

```
{
        "location": {
            "coordinates": [
                -118.376354,
                34.063584
            ],
            "type": "Point"
        },
        "addressLines": [
            "257 S. La Cienega Blvd.",
            "Beverly Hills, CA 90211"
        ],
        "_id": "600d1f521efed638d808d32e",
        "storeName": "La Cienega & Gregory Way",
        "phoneNumber": "310-659-9562",
        "address": {
            "streetAddressLine1": "257 S. La Cienega Blvd.",
            "streetAddressLine2": null,
            "streetAddressLine3": null,
            "city": "Beverly Hills",
            "countrySubdivisionCode": "CA",
            "countryCode": "US",
            "postalCode": "902113301"
        },
        "openStatusText": "Open until 6:00 PM",
        "__v": 0
    },
```

Comment: I'm not seeing a "name" key in your JSON. And what does your entire request JSON look like?

Comment: Just Added into the question, take a look!! @DaMahdi03

Comment: In your first `app.get` what does `req` look like because if it's just that one store then the `.forEach` won't work because it's not an array

Answer (score 0):

stores must be array to be possible to use forEach method to iterate over it